# What front-end frameworks did they use to build websites for mobile?

Tags: web-development, angularjs, bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to make a website (rather than mobile apps) mainly for mobile by `Angular 5`. Initially I plan to just use `Bootstrap` to make it responsive. However, when I see lots of websites opened in mobile browsers, I notice that a same url can return very different views in desktop and mobile. So I guess they are proposing 2 different views for desktop and mobile, and the mobile view does not seem to be done by `Bootstrap`. Here are 2 examples in mobile:

[image] . 
[image]

If frameworks like `Ionic`, `React Native`, `Apache Cordova` help people build mobile apps, could anyone suggest me any framework to help build mobile websites?

Comment: Stack Overflow uses ASP.net, more than likely they used RESS.